# Application insights slack integration

Tags: azure-application-insights, slack

I've recently started using application insights with a web api.

It will be really helpful to configure app insights to post error messages in a slack channel.

I've seen there is a slack connector but I am not sure how to use it, my guess is that this can be solved with the slack connector and a azure logic app, any tips? tutorials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have a look at this link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/demos/alert-to-slack-with-logic-app. I followed the instruction and it worked for me.

The tricky part is you need to click the "Deploy to Azure" button on this link page. It would redirect you to Azure Portal, and you will need to specify which channel you want the alert message to be sent e.g. #somechannel. Don't use direct message like @yourname, it has some problem with that and the logic app couldn't deploy for me.

Then you just follow the instruction to find the deployed logic app and authenticate it by logging into slack. And you also need get the logic app URI from the deployment output as in the instruction. Once you put the URI into the alert webhook, you are ready to go!

Comment: I can't test this for now, but it looks like a good solution, I will mark it as answer and review this once I can test it.

Answer (score 4):

It's relatively easy to set up a slack webhook.

There's a pretty good C# nuget package for this at https://github.com/nerdfury/Slack.Webhooks

Although you'd need to set up a seperate service to poll and route the app insights data.

There's also commercial options.

getcloudbot.com allows you to hook your Azure Application Insights bundle directly into your slack channel. It's good at staying on top of your services. 
Disclaimer : I run it.

Comment: We're using getcloudbot.com, really neat for reports and slack integration with Appliction Insights

Comment: Any idea if the Cloudbot for Azure by FreevolutLTD that links to getcloudbot.com is still legit?  1 review and not a lot of other internet presence.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure an alert for your error messages https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-alerts
And then configure sending to Slack using web hooks: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Create-Azure-Alerts-with-b938077a

Answer (score 0):

Another quick solution to this, which doesn't involve additional code or a logic app, is to set up a Slack email integration, which provides you an inbound email address for a given channel.  You can use that in Application Insights in the "Additional administrator email(s)" field.

This isn't perfect, as you don't really get a lot of details in the post to slack, but it will notify you and provide the name of the alert.

Comment: And it also requires a slack subscription

Comment: @Calin You don't need a slack's subscription if you use [MailClark](https://mailclark.ai). The bot is still in beta for one week, but after, it have a freemium plan. I'm part of the team, if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest path that I found to integrate was using an app named Slack Email which sends email alerts to slack. Once you subscribe this email id to alerts in Application Insights it will start sending the messages on the specific channel you have linked the email to.
https://teamesub.slack.com/apps/A0F81496D-email